# What different urls are there for a Google+ profile URL

Tags: google-plus

Google+ Profile URLs come in various forms. For instance

- https://plus.google.com/+LukasBombach/
- https://plus.google.com/u/0/+LukasBombach/
- https://plus.google.com/116410159423843133916
- https://plus.google.com/u/0/116410159423843133916

basically, what you can see, is the URL is either the `+Name` or the `UserId` and it is either prefixed by `/u/{n}/` or not.

Are there any other patterns and/or is there a documentation on how Google+ URLs can look like? Thank you

*edit: This is also valid*

- https://plus.google.com/b/116410159423843133916/+LukasBombach

Comment: Take a look at https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2676340

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman Thank you, I have read that page. I don't see any information on different URL schemes

Comment: What is your motivation to know *all* URLs to visit a Google+ profile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **TL;DR:**
>   `/\/(u\/\d+\/)?((wm\/[^\/]+)|(b\/\d{21})\/)?(\d{21}|\+[\w_\p{L}-]+)(\/[a-z]+)?\/?/i`

### Vanity URLs

Google+ allowed users to get their vanity URL. This is nothing more than an **alternative link** to their Google+ Profile Page (as `+MyName` is easier to remember than `012345678901234567890`).
Not everyone has a vanity URL (this is not a required step to create a Google+ profile), so you can indifferently access a profile page through both URLs:

- `https://plus.google.com/012345678901234567890/`
- `https://plus.google.com/+MyName/`

### Multi-login

The `/u/0` simply means you're connected.

Google supports multi-login, and needs to differentiate these accounts. If you've got a single account connected, you'll always see these `/u/0`, but if you've got more than one account connected, you're supposed to see `/u/1`, `/u/2` and so on... depending on your current account.
If you're not connected to your Google account, you're not supposed to see it (unless it's an already shared URL, of course).

When you share this kind of URL, it's better to avoid any `/u/x`. An user connected on his #2 account and clicking on a `/u/1` URL will be switched on his #1 account, and that's probably no what he wants.

If you're trying to access a `/u/1` URL (or more) without using multiples accounts, you'll always be redirected to the `/u/0` version.

You can find the same behavior in most of Google products, as Gmail (`mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox`).

As this multi-login specificity is related to the user **reading** the profile page, this means you can access a profile page through these URLs:

- `https://plus.google.com/u/0/+MyName/`
- `https://plus.google.com/u/1/+MyName/`
- `https://plus.google.com/u/2/+MyName/`
- ...

### Autocorrected URLs

You may know Google products often change. This means an old URL could be broken today. On a Google+ profile, you can access to several pages: `/about`, `/posts`, `/photos`, `/videos`...
Maybe there has been/will have other pages, so Google decided to avoid broken URLs leading to a non-existent page (or URLs with an ending typo). To do this, they replace every alphabetical string which is not a real page by `/posts` (the default page).
This means you can access a profile page through these URLs:

- `https://plus.google.com/+MyName/whatever`

### Referers

The `/b/` option seems to have an analytic purpose (even if I didn't found anything about this). This option only accepts a valid user id. It *could* be compared to the StackOverflow share URL : `http://stackoverflow.com/q/<sharer id>/<post id>`.
Anyway, this has no incidence on the destination page, so we can user these URLs:

- `https://plus.google.com/b/012345678901234567890/+MyName/`

### Other

I found another option, which I still hadn't identify: `/wm/`.
It works in the same way `/b/` do, but accepts anything but a `/`:

- `https://plus.google.com/wm/_-*~wh4tever~*-_/+MyName/`

### Finally...

You just have to know `/b/` can't be combined with `/wm/`, and then you can make this sweetty regex ♥

```
/\/(u\/\d+\/)?((wm\/[^\/]+)|(b\/\d{21})\/)?(\d{21}|\+[\w_\p{L}-]+)(\/[a-z]+)?\/?/i
```

Comment: Wow this is the hell of an answer. Thank you.